# Parsing hashtags in twitter API PHP

Tags: php, regex, twitter, hashtag

I want to parse hashtags from the tweets I'm retrieving from twitter. Now, I didn't find anything available in the api. So, I'm parsing it on my own using php. I've tried several things.

```
<?php
$subject = "This is a simple #hashtag";
$pattern = "#\S*\w";
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

I've also tried

```
$pattern = "/[#]"."[A-Za-z0-9-_]"."/g";
```

But then it shows /g isn't recognized by php. I've been trying to do this for quite a long time now but am not being able to do this. So please help.

P.S. : I've a very little idea about Regular Experssions.

Comment: The first one didn't work because you didn't specify the delimiters, the slashes at the beginning and the end. PHP doesn't recognize the `g`-flag because preg_match_all automatically matches all occurences (and that's what that flag does). You might want to try `/#[a-z0-9\-_]+/i`? Note: the `i`-flag makes the regex case-insensitive.

Comment: `/g` == the `_all` in `preg_match_all()`. In the first, you forgot your delimiters for the regex, in the second, you have a wrong modifier. Either of the 2 would work pretty ok-ish if those things are fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Actually I tried "/[#][A-Za-z0-9-_]/" also. Then it said that no delimiter had been specified. Then I tried "/[#][A-Za-z0-9-_][/\t]".. Then it said unknown modifier ' '.

Comment: But what if I want to specify the end of the regexp I'm searching for. Is there something wrong with "/[#][A-Za-z0-9-][/\t]"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider where a hashtag might appear. There are three cases:

- at the beginning of a tweet,
- after whitespace,
- in the middle of a word - this must not be counted as a hashtag.

So this will match them correctly:

```
'/(^|\s)\#\w+/'
```

Explanation:

- `^` can be used in *OR* statements
- `\s` is used to catch spaces, tabs and new lines

Here is the complete code:

```
<?php
$subject = "#hashtag This is a simple #hashtag hello world #hastag2 last string not-a-hash-tag#hashtag3 and yet not -#hashtag";
$pattern = "/(?:^|\s)(\#\w+)/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot.
I just read more about Regular Expressions. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$subject = "This is a simple #hashtag hello world #hastag2 last string #hashtag3";
$pattern = "/(#\w+)/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. But is it different from "/[#][A-Za-z0-9-]/" ?

Comment: This will match also hashtags in the middle of words which are not hashtags.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way using object prototypes, wrote a post detailing exactly how to do this with not only hastags, but usernames and URLs within tweets. Needed it for [a project](https://benmarshall.me/twitscreen/) I'm working on where I'm grabbing tweets from the Twitter API.

https://benmarshall.me/parse-twitter-hashtags/

Here's the relevant code:

```
// Auto-link URLs in a string
// Usage: mystring.parseURL()
String.prototype.parseURL = function() {
  return this.replace(/[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&~\?\/.=]+/g, function( url ) {
    return url.link( url );
  });
};

// Auto-link Twitter usernames in a string
// Usage: mystring.parseUsername()
String.prototype.parseUsername = function() {
  return this.replace(/[@]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g, function( u ) {
    var username = u.replace("@","");

    return u.link( 'http://twitter.com/' + username );
  });
};

// Auto-link Twitter hashtags in a string
// Usage: mystring.parseHashtag()
String.prototype.parseHashtag = function() {
  return this.replace(/[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g, function( t ) {
    var tag = t.replace("#","%23");

    return t.link( 'http://search.twitter.com/search?q=' + tag );
  });
};
```